# How to display items of struts2 iterator independently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I am using struts iterator tag to display the result of `arraylist` on my `jsp` page. My problem is that I want item  as independent item so that I can use it for more processing as I want each item as hyperlink to different pages.

```
<ol>
  <s:iterator value="ls">
    <li> 
      <a href="javascript:document.form1.submit();">
        <s:property />
      </a>
    </li>
   </s:iterator>
 </ol>
```

I am not able to target each `li` independently. I need the text of each list item so that I can send it in form as hidden variable. My problem is targeting `li's` independently.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "targeting `<li>`'s independently". If you want to hyperlink to different pages then create a link with something like an ID or other unique identifier that can be used by the target page to retrieve data.

Comment: arraylist contains the set values retrieved from database each database value has to have a specific action  associated to it...thats why i need to click or target or whatever u want to call it .

Comment: Then create links with a unique identifier as I said. I don't know why you need a form to do this.

Comment: @user3763571 If you want to manage pages in such way, it's not easy so, better try any CMS available.

Comment: @user3763571 can you add more informations ? Expected result vs current result, and what have you tried, even with pseudo code ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
<ol>
  <s:iterator value="ls">
    <li> 
      <a href="javascript:doSubmit(this)">
        <s:property />
      </a>
    </li>
   </s:iterator>
 </ol>
<s:hidden name="name" id="idHidden"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function doSubmit(val){
   $("idHidden").val(val.value);
   document.form1.submit();
 }
</script>
```